# Zend Lucene or sphinx?

Tags: php, zend-framework, sphinx, zend-search-lucene

I am building a system that has database operations that has millions of records.I am using Zend Framework in all part of my project.I wanted to use a search indexing technique but have you got any advice on this?which technique should i use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: for that scale (millions of records) i would suggest sphinx. but 'scale' is one only factor. sphinx comes with far more options. depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,andreas.And where should i start from?Any suggestion on sphinx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zend Lucene absolutely unrelevant for "millions of records".

Try to use sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html.

It has many usefull fratures, including clasterization to many servers; smart, customizable result ranking and much more. And it is really fast.
PHP API docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php

There is C-version of PHP API http://pecl.php.net/package/sphinx

Comment: Sphinx is especially useful because of its MySQL native integration, simplyfying infrastructure.

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely don't want to use Zend Framework's Lucene implementation for that many records.  Lucene is a great idea, just not a pure-PHP version.

Check out [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), two Lucene-based search services that may fit your needs well.  ElasticSearch is *incredibly* usable right out of the box with effectively zero configuration.